# How to create a custom webhook URL per address via API

Tags: callback, notifications, webhooks, coinbase-api

We are creating a custom payment service that uses Coinbase as a Bitcoin backbone. I managed to set up Bitcoin address creation (wallets) and the checkout process is actually finished (Bitcoin address is being created).

However, I did not find a way to **attach a custom callback URL to an address** I've created. The address should "listen" to incoming transactions and trigger the webhook URL.

***We cannot use any of the predigested merchant solutions*** from Coinbase (button / page / iframe) because the payment flow should be deeply integrated into our existing processes, look and feel. Instead the system is just creating a new Bitcoin address and should be notified on incoming transaction events, but **without** using a merchant solution.

When creating an address using the [Coinbase API v2](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2), you get an object that includes the `callback_url` property. However, it is empty and in the documentation there is no hint on how to specify that.

I thought about polling the addresses, but that could easily exceed the *10,000 requests per hour* rate limit. Any clues how to specify the `callback_url` on address creation (`https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id/addresses`)?

Comment: Got any solution

Comment: Not with coinbase. I now use a 3rd party blockchain API service to check incoming transactions as they occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d recommend a third-party for this - I’ve personally used https://blockchainwebhooks.com and https://www.blockcypher.com - both have been reliable and offer free plans. Blockchain WebHooks is significantly more affordable, that’s what we still used today.